# how to delete relationship's index via REST API

Tags: rest, graph, neo4j

I can't found any methods delete relationship's index in [REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api.html).
but I can delete relationship's index through neo4j webadmin tool.
neo4j server's stable release version 1.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to send a HTTP DELETE to `http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/relationship/[indexname]` ?